# How to run GWT RequestFactory Validation Tool on Eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, gwt, requestfactory

I've got a Android AppEngine Connected Project I'm trying to build using GWT2.4 RequestFactory and Objectify on my Eclipse IDE.

Apparently I need to run the RequestFactory Validation Tool because I'm using ServiceName and ProxyForName annotations (these are required especially when working on the Android client side).  My problem is the Eclipse can't validate it and the solution provided at http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/RequestFactoryInterfaceValidation#IDE_configuration is enough to make me rip my eyes out.

Since I'm working on a Windows machine, the shell script provided is not very useful.  Trying to run Validation Tool from a cmd propt returns the error message:"This tool must be run with a JDK, not a JRE"

Can someone explain how this Tool is supposed to be run?  Is there a way to use it as an External Tool in eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally if you follow carefully the instructions in the link you show, and run the GWT Development Mode from Eclipse, the Validation should be done automatically at the time you access the development URL with your browser.

For the record, I've actually had some problems with it, but launching the application several times maked it work.

Comment: I would be inclined to agree with you, mainly because I had it working previously (I honestly don't know why or how).  The difference was that when it worked it also took care of the validation warnings for Request factory ("Cannot fully validate context since domain type com...foo is not available").  This time it doesn't.  The annotation processor is setup correctly.  I can't be 100% sure the problem lies with the Validation Tool not running, but having those warnings reappear makes me suspect it is so...

Comment: I'm not an expert, so let's hope someone more qualified can help you! In the meantime apart from a deep workspace cleaning/rebuid I don't have any more idea to help you :(

Comment: Do you have an entry like this in the .factorypath at the root of your project? `<factorypathentry kind="EXTJAR" id="D:\eclipse37\plugins\com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.v201201120043-rel-r37\gwt-2.4.0\requestfactory-apt.jar" enabled="true" runInBatchMode="false"/>`

Comment: Yep.  I ended up going to a previous build and starting from scratch.  Now it works.  It still bugs me that I can't pin the actual problem.  I have to go with your initial suggestion that Validation Tool runs automatically.  But in that case I wish I knew what made it break...  thanks for the assist!

Comment: Is there a way to make it relative. So that anyone who checks it out, no matter what sdk bundle version of plugin he/she has this will work out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ran into the same problem as well. When I tried annotation processing (under Java Compiler-> Annotation processing )was being disabled. So RequestFactoryDeobfuscatorBuilder was not being generated. Try enabling that and rebuilding your project.

Answer (score 0):

I've just recovered from two days of hunting this bug down in a project that used to run validation properly but stopped.

In my case I had a new-ish generic BaseRequestContext and a specific sub-interface that extended it. My parent interface declared a method that didn't match the Locator's exactly (e.g. getThing(T) vs get(T)) and this wasn't reported as an error but did stop the validation tool from completing.

Answer (score 0):

Apt is also removed in Java 8 : http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/117 . So beware.

Switching back to Java 7 will fix the issue if you are using Java 8.

Answer (score -1):

I understood why the error happens sometimes in a project: the compiler was complaining it cannot find the directory .apt . But when I tried to create it manually it was not possible (under windows). I think the validation tool mutes the exception of not being able to create the directory: try renaming .apt in your validation tool calls (do a text search in your project)